# Alfresco, embed a binary inside the amp

Tags: alfresco, binaryfiles, software-distribution

I have an alfresco community amp module, which also need a client msi to be installed on the client PC. 
To solve the distribution problem I tought about embedding the installer inside the amp to give the user the possibility to download it and install it when needed.

It is a correct approach? and which is the best correct to put the biniry file in?

The file should be downloaded from a link inside alfresco share, displayed when the user permorm some actions on a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem with `maven-resoures-plugin` configured as followed. Maybe this is not the best options, but it worked.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>msi</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>/src/main/myLib</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/amp/web/myShare/js/myLib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```